# Pascal static and dynamic scope prob?

Tags: dynamic, static, scope, pascal

If pascal was using dynamic scope what it would be the result of this code ??
By using the static scope i get those results!
x=32 , y=39 and z=105

```
program what(output);

var 
  y, z: integer;

procedure p(x, z: integer);

  procedure a(y: integer);
  begin (* of procedure a *)
    writeln(x, y, z);
    x := x + 5;
  end;

  procedure b(x:integer);
  begin (* of procedure b *)
    writeln(x, y, z);
    y := y + 2;
    a(x + 7);
  end;
begin (* of procedure p *)
  b(32);
  writeln(x, y, z);
  a(47);
  writeln(x, y, z);
end;

procedure q(x,y:integer);
begin (* of procedure q *)
  p(x + 4, x + y);
  writeln(x, y, z);
end;

begin (* of program what *)
  y := 21; 
  z := 105; 
  q(y + 1, y + z);
  writeln(y, z);
end.
```

Comment: Which sort of Pascal is this ? It cannot compile in any which I know so far.

Comment: @TLama: Surprisingly, it actually compiles. It generates a `[dcc32 Warning] Project1.dpr(30): W1011 Text after final 'END.' - ignored by compiler`, but XE5 compiles it. ???

Comment: I don't get the same results: The final output I get is Y = 23, Z = 105.

Comment: @Ken, so the name `what` is on a place :-) Wow, it compiles also in Delphi 2009. Compiler parser probably ignores everything from the first non-alphanumeric char after the program name till the semicolon. Assuming this would be a Delphi or FPC application, it is still missing a console pragma.

Comment: @TLama: Actually, if you clean up the formatting and spacing, it's not near as bad as it appears. I'm posting a cleaner version (as an edit) to clarify the question a little.

Comment: @TLama: See the help file. In XE5's docwiki, it's [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Programs_and_Units), under `The Program Heading`: In standard Pascal, a program heading can include parameters after the program name: `program Calc(input, output);` Embarcadero's **Delphi ignores these parameters**. (**Emphasis** mine.)

Comment: They are filehandles iirc. The first two are stdin and out, the rest are extra files. IIRC some old OS (VMS?) required all files to be accessed to be declared on the cmdline. Files that are so declared but aren't assigned are temporary files. ( The GNU Pascal site, and Scott Moore's faq have some info on this. (ISO Pascal). TP already did skip this, FPC also does so, but for the ISO mode that is actually a bug :-)

Answer (score 0):

I assume the main difference would be that function a() would see its caller's ("b()"'s) x, and not the one from the parent procedure (p).

Comment: Yes. The issue here has nothing to do with "dynamic" and "static"; it's a variable scoping issue (local variables being visible instead of variables wider in scope). This may help: [`Blocks and Scope`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Declarations_and_Statements#Blocks_and_Scope), specifically the section on Scope - the table with the visibility rules is pretty clear.

Comment: Actually, the same section has a section right below "Scope" called "Naming conflicts" that explains the issue pretty well.

Comment: No afaik dynamic/static scoping is the proper term. Static is fixed compiletime as Delphi/Pascal in general, dynamic means that the exact call chain matters for scoping. This is usually something for scripting languages though. (and usually that hits a scaling bottleneck soon)